# Scrapy to parse multiple URLs into a single json

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Currently using scrapy with multiple URLs on the start_urls parameter which I load like this:

```
    with open('urllist.txt') as f:
        start_urls = f.read().splitlines()
```

Then, I parse it the page with this code:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    yield {
            'date': datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),
            'item': response.xpath("//font[contains(@id, 'item')]/a/text()").get(),
            'price': response.xpath("//font[contains(@id, 'price')]/a/text()").get(),
          }
```

It works fine, but the resulting json file looks like this (notice two lines per execution):

```
{"date": "05/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 1", "price": "6.80"}
{"date": "05/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 2", "price": "8.50"}
{"date": "06/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 1", "price": "6.70"}
{"date": "06/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 2", "price": "8.50"}
```

My expectation was something like:

```
{"scans": [
    {"date": "05/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 1", "price": "6.80"},
    {"date": "05/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 2", "price": "8.50"},
    {"date": "06/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 1", "price": "6.70"},
    {"date": "06/01/2023 02:39:49", "item": "Item 2", "price": "8.50"}]}
```

Should I post-process the results to add the "scans" level? I will later import this on a page and ajax doesn't like broken JSON files.

Comment: So each item is being scraped correctly you just want them all placed into the list which is the value of the "scans" key? is that right?  Are the results being written to a file ever?

Comment: @Alexander yes, the items are being scraped correctly. I just want to change the output so the json has that format. Yes, the results are sent to the file.